# Monotouch: UINavigationController, set the RootViewController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, rootview

How is it possible to map the initWithRootViewController objective-c method in Monotouch?

From Miguel de Icaza Rosetta site, I've found the following translation but I don't know how to apply it:

```
Selector: initWithRootViewController:
Method: IntPtr Constructor (UIViewController rootViewController);
```

Then, I also have another problem to solve. I would **change the UINavigationController RootViewController during runtime**. Is it possible? Surfing the Web, I've found this [Changing a UINavigationController’s Root View Controller](http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/changing-a-uinavigationcontroller%E2%80%99s-root-view-controller/). Is there a more simple solution?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: my goal is to map the initWithRootViewController method (provided in the link) in Monotouch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question - you simply create a new `UINavigationController` as below:

```
UINavigationController navController = new UINavigationController(rootViewController);
```

Technically it would be possible to change the root controller by modifying the `ViewControllers` property. For example:

```
navController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[2] { newRootController, childController }
```

**EDIT**

Try adding the following constructor to your custom `UINavigationController`:

```
public CustomNavController(UIViewController rootViewController)
{
    ViewControllers = new UIViewController[1] { rootViewController };
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to get it done, but it'll work.

Comment: Hi Luke, thank you. The first answer doesn't work for me. I haven't a ctr that takes an UIViewController. Could you help me on adopt the solution I provided in the above link. I would create a custom navigationcontroller but I can't understand how to use rosetta. Thank you again.

Comment: What is your app's hierarchy like? You've got a little confused as to why this won't work for you..

Comment: beacause I haven't a ctr like the one you provided. Check the edit.

Comment: Could try adding the constructor I've added in the edit. That'll provide the easiest solution of initially setting the rootViewController. About to head into a meeting so don't have time to help with the second problem right now but if I get a moment later, I'll see what I can do

Comment: Thank you very much. I've added the ctr. Do I have to call it with any base method?`public CustomNavController(UIViewController rootViewController) : base ...` thank you!